# GUI freezes when text and progressbar changes

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I'm creating a program that uses a TextBox and a ProgressBar and each time the text changes in the TextBox or the ProgressBar performs a step the GUI freezes and I can't do anything until the operation is done.

I know I need to run them on a different thread but I searched the entire web and didn't find a method that works for me.

This is an example when I write a file and I need to get the progress of it:

```
for (int l = 0; l < newfile.Length; l++)
{
  vfswriter.Write(newfile[l]);
  double percentage = ((double)l / (double)newfile.Length * 100);
  this.progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
}
```

and this is an example when I change text:

```
this.richTextBox1.Text = "Installing patch : ";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see an attempt to use a BackgroundWorker. That could help.

Comment: i tried but my code goes like this: i call a method and in the method it uses the text and backgroundworker

Comment: Just as a side note - you could lose the `percentage` variable and just code the progress bar update as `this.progressBar1.Value = l * 100 / newfile.Length;`. Integer maths would do what you want just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `BackgroundWorker`, put your for loop inside of `DoWork` method:

```
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += doWork;

private void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < newfile.Length; l++)
    {
       vfswriter.Write(newfile[l]);
       double percentage = ((double)l / (double)newfile.Length * 100);
       this.progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    }
}
```

When you want to execute your loop call `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` method.

Also you can use `ProgressChanged` event to update your progress bar:

```
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += doWork;
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += progressChanged;

private void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < newfile.Length; l++)
    {
       vfswriter.Write(newfile[l]);
       double percentage = ((double)l / (double)newfile.Length * 100);
       var value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(value);
    }
}

private void progressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Update: If you want to pass arguments to `DoWork` method you can do it when you calling the `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` method like this:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(argument);
```

And you can access it in `DoWork` method with the `e.Argument`. if you want to pass more than one argument you can do the trick with [`Anonymous Types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).For example:

```
var myArguments = new { Property1 = "some value", Property2 = myId, Property3 = myList };
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(myArguments);
```

In DoWork method:

```
dynamic arguments = e.Argument;
var arg1 = arguments.Property1;
var arg2 = arguments.Property2;
// and so on...
```

Comment: You aren't using ReportProgress.  You are updating the GUI from the background thread.

Comment: @LarsTech now I have added that :-)

Comment: How can i pass arguments to the DoWork ?

Comment: @Meydan when you calling `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` you can pass your argument: `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(parameter);` and in DoWork method you can access it by: `e.Argument`

Comment: what if i need 2 arguments ? because in the code there is 
vfswriter and newfile

Comment: @Meydan then you can pass argument as  [Anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) and access it properties and parse it in the DoWork method

Comment: It doesnt work, in the DoWork it doesnt recognize the Property1 or Property2

Comment: @Meydan then try this: `"dynamic arguments = e.Argument;"` Here is a screenshot from my debug: http://imgur.com/8z2oKWh

Comment: @Meydan, if this answer solve your problem please consider accept this as an answer.

Comment: instead of the annonymus i used a list<object> but i have a problem
the backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(list); is in a for loop so it sends an exception saying the background is in use even tough i dispose the backgroundworker when it completes

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Task class to create and run background threads. A word of caution! Any time you want to update something from a thread that is not the main thread, you must use the Dispatcher to run code on the main thread.

My example code:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
{
 for (int l = 0; l < newfile.Length; l++)
 {
   vfswriter.Write(newfile[l]);
   double percentage = ((double)l / (double)newfile.Length * 100);
   //This runs the code inside it on the main thread (required for any GUI actions
   App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) (() =>
   {
     this.progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
   }
 }
});
task.Start();
```